# getjson with jquery mobile from json file formatted as a list of lists

Tags: json, jquery-mobile

I'm running nagios on Slackware and I am using `mklivestatus` to get a json output for the hosts. The file is formatted like this

```
   [["localhost","127.0.0.1",0]]
```

How can i use the `$.getJSON()` to get the values and append them in html page? Or is there a way to change the json file to have this format:

```
{["host_name":localhost","host_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":0]}
```

With the above format I'm using this code and works fine

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('status.json', function(data) {
        var output = '';

        $.each(data, function(index, value){

            output += '<option value="'+value.host_name+'">'+value.host_name+' ('+value.status+')</option>';

        });

        $('#page').html(output);

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems:

1. Most importantly `[["localhost","127.0.0.1",0]]` is an array of arrays, so treat it like one. Instead of `value.host_name` use index to access it's members `value[0]`.
2. Use appropriate event jQM handler (e.g. `pageinit`)
3. And I guess you wanted to insert `<option>`s to a `select` element, not a page.

Now, given that you have following markup

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="content">    
        <select id="select1">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

you populate your select menu like this

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page", function(){
    $.getJSON("status.json", function(data){
        var output = '';
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            output += '<option value="'+value[0]+'">'+value[1]+' ('+value[2]+')</option>';
        });
        $('#select1').html(output);
    });
});
```

**P.S.** BTW this is invalid JSON

```
{["host_name":localhost","host_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":0]}
```

It should be

```
[{"host_name":localhost","host_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":0}]
```

Comment: I managed to get it work like this: data[index][0]. Your way is better though. Thank you very much for your help. You're right about the invalid Json. I was careless when i wrote it.